# MySql multiplicação entre valores do tipo decimal perde a precisão

Tags: mysql

Em  minha aplicação necessito de precisão para valores numéricos de 12 casas decimais. Criei o seguinte teste:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE (
     VALOR1 DECIMAL(16,12),
     VALOR2 DECIMAL(16,12),
     VALOR3 DECIMAL(16,12) )

INSERT INTO TESTE (VALOR1, VALOR2)
VALUES ( 0.0001445312, 128)


UPDATE TESTE SET VALOR3 = VALOR1 * VALOR2


select valor3 from teste

valor3
0.0185
```

O valor correto seria de 0.0184999936, o MySql arredonda para 4 casas decimais.

Como conseguir o resultado correto de 0.0184999936 sem o arredondamento?

Comment: Pra mim tá dando certo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d02e0/1

Comment: O MySQL não faz arredondamento "por conta própria". Provavelmente o problema é na aplicação que você está usando para acessar. Recomendo testar com o cliente oficial de linha de comando, ou com o MySQL Workbench (ou ainda MySQL Query Browser).

Comment: Eu estou usando MySql WorkBenck para fazer os teste em um SO Windows 7.

Comment: @dluisbr teste com VALOR1 * VALOR2 * 10000 pra ver se é problema de exibição (se aparecem mais casas). O teste que você colocou na pergunta é exatamente a situação real do DB?

Comment: Testei com o cliente oficial de linha de comando e continua arredondando para 0.0185. Pode ser alguma configuração do BD ou dos SO?

Comment: Fiz o mesmo aqui com MySQL de um servidor em produção e não houve arredondamento. Qual a versão do MySQL? Tem certeza que o que você colocou na pergunta é exatamente o teste que está fazendo?

Comment: Lembrando que `teste` e `TESTE` são tabelas diferentes em princípio, o que é um erro do exemplo dado na pergunta - para ser portátil a solução, deve escrever tudo com casing igual (o OS interfere nisso). Se estiver usando um ambiente case sensitive, verifique de não ter duas tabelas com nome teste.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxa1h.png

Comment: Já tentou `UPDATE TESTE SET VALOR3 = CAST((VALOR1 * VALOR2) AS DECIMAL(16,12));` ?

Comment: Bacco o relatado na questão acima é exatamente como executei no banco, no meu ambiente não é case sensiteve.

Comment: Maurivan, executei a sua sugestão anteriormente antes de postar a questão e continua arredondando.

Comment: A versão do MySql que estou usando é 5.5.36 Community Server (GPL).

Comment: Problema solucionado.

Comment: Desinstalei o MySql e instalei a ultima versão 5.7.17 e refiz o teste, acima descrito, funcionou conforme o esperado.